# How to send MQ message without RFH header in C?

Tags: c, ibm-mq

How to send MQ message without RFH header in C or in other words how do i send NonJMS MQ message using 'C' library interface?

Basically, is there any 'C' equivalent of

```
((com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueue) queue).setTargetClient(JMSC.MQJMS_CLIENT_NONJMS_MQ);
```

Following 'C' MQ calls I am making

```
MQCONNX(qmgrName, &mqcno, &hConn_, &compCode, &cReason);
MQOPEN(hConn_, &od, openOptions, &hObj_, &openCode, &reason)
MQCRTMH(hConn_, &cmho, &hMsg, &createCode, &reason)
MQSETMP(hConn_, hMsg, &smpo, &prop, &pd, MQTYPE_STRING, propVal.length(), propVal, &compCode, &reason);
pmo.Version = MQPMO_VERSION_3;
pmo.OriginalMsgHandle = hMsg;
MQPUT(hConn_, hObj_, NULL, &pmo, msg._theMessage.length(), buffer, &compCode, &reason);
MQDLTMH(hConn_, &hMsg, &dmho, &compCode, &reason);
```

pmo.OriginalMsgHandle = hMsg **//This line is causing RFH header**

MQ Receiver is giving following output. I am using C++ MQ interface to receive the message because that's what existing code is doing and need to make sure that C generated msgs can be read by C++ receiver

```
2024489 - 2019-09-26 09:00:05.691154 Receiver: Received Message from MQ of size 490
2024489 - 2019-09-26 09:00:05.691163 Receiver: Received Message from MQ --> RFH ^B
```

```
std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string (this=0x6ce7938,
    __str="RFH \002\000\000\000P\000\000\000\"\002\000\000\063\003\000\000MQSTR   \000\000\000\000\270\004\000\000(\000\000\000<usr><GROUP_ID>1</GROUP_ID></usr> corrId: \"CORR_ID\"\nchannel: \"HIFI\"\nemp
Ids {\n    empId {\n        type: \"CALLER_NO\"\n        value: \"123456"...)
```

Answer (score 2):

The IBM MQ classes for JMS API and the XMS APIs (C++ and .NET) are the only APIs that default to sending a RFH2 header.

The setting below that you mention is specific to the JMS API (there would be something similar or the same for XMS) and tells the API that the app receiving the message is not a JMS app so do not send the RFH2 header:

```
((com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueue) queue).setTargetClient(JMSC.MQJMS_CLIENT_NONJMS_MQ);
```

---

If you are using the C API to send messages it will NOT have a RFH2 header so there is no setting to turn off what is not sent.

Comment: Thx for your reply. I am not sure I am seeing RFH header. Received Message from MQ --> RFH ^B –

Comment: I just figured out that pmo.OriginalMsgHandle = hMsg **This line is causing RFH header** Though not sure how do i make it still pass message property without adding the RFH header

Comment: What version of mq are you using on the receiver side?

Comment: C++ classes can not use message properties, this is probably why it is converted to a RFH2.

Comment: MQ 9 Though just found out that pmo.Version = MQPMO_VERSION_3; is causing it. It works fine with MQPMO_VERSION_2 but not sure if property will work with VERSION_2 or not.

Comment: I think it is adding RFH header, not because of C++ in the receiver but because I am using VERSION_3 and message property.

Comment: It seems that message properties will always have RFH header

Comment: I think I mentioned it did not support message properties in the other question.  Can you please answer my question on that?

Comment: The question was: Is there a difference in the content/payload of the messages are sent to server instance 1 and server instance 2?

Comment: no diff in content/payload. Though response is sent to different destination by each instance hence it is important to receive response by same instance that sent the request originally.

Comment: @VikasAgrawal  is the concern that you have two instances of a sending app (ex: sendapp1 and sendapp2) that get sent down stream to two instances of a responding app (ex: respondapp1 and respondapp2) and you want to ensure that the responses go back to the same sendapp instance that sent it? If that is the case then I think you can accomplish this in a much better way you may not be aware of.  I can explain it in my answer if that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways for a C program to handle JMS (aka MQRFH2) messages.

As you saw, the default behavior is for GMO ***Options*** field to have *MQGMO_PROPERTIES_AS_Q_DEF* and the queue's ***Property Control*** attribute to be set to ***Compatibility***. Hence, when your application gets a message, it will have the MQRFH2 structure.

If you changed the GMO ***Options*** field to have *MQGMO_PROPERTIES_IN_HANDLE* then when your application gets a message, it will receives just the message payload and all of the message properties will be available via the message handle.

In the sample MQ programs included with IBM MQ, there is one called ***amqsbcg0.c***.  There are 2 builds of it: amqsbcg (bindings mode) and amqsbcgc (client mode).

It takes up to 3 parameters: QueueName, QMgrName and PropertyOptions

(1) If you run it without any property options or property options set to 0 then it will set GMO Options field to have MQGMO_PROPERTIES_AS_Q_DEF.  Hence, if the message on the queue is a JMS message then the program will output an MQRFH2 structure.

(2) If you run it with property options set to 1 then it will set GMO Options field to have MQGMO_PROPERTIES_IN_HANDLE.  Hence, if the message on the queue is a JMS message then then program will output the message properties followed by the message payload.